# Different threads synchronizing on different objects

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, monitors

Please look at this code

```
public class Test extends Thread {
    int i;
    public Test(int i) {this.i = i;}

    void simpleBlock() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println(i + " this is an example of a thread blocking on itself - practicing concurrency 101, monitors, etc.");
        synchronized(this) {wait();}
    }

    public void run() {
        try {simpleBlock();} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}
```

This is implemented by a Main class that creates and starts the threads

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Test[] t = new Test[20];
        for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
            t[i] = new Test(i);
            t[i].start();
        }
    }
}
```

this prints the following output

```
0 this is an example of a thread blocking on itself - practicing concurrency 101, monitors, etc.
6 this is an example of a thread blocking on itself - practicing concurrency 101, monitors, etc.
4 this is an example of a thread blocking on itself - practicing concurrency 101, monitors, etc.
3 this is an example of a thread blocking on itself - practicing concurrency 101, monitors, etc.
5 this is an example of a thread blocking on itself - practicing concurrency 101, monitors, etc.
2 this is an example of a thread blocking on itself - practicing concurrency 101, monitors, etc.
1 this is an example of a thread blocking on itself - practicing concurrency 101, monitors, etc.
14 this is an example of a thread blocking on itself - practicing concurrency 101, monitors, etc.
7 this is an example of a thread blocking on itself - practicing concurrency 101, monitors, etc.
13 this is an example of a thread blocking on itself - practicing concurrency 101, monitors, etc.
12 this is an example of a thread blocking on itself - practicing concurrency 101, monitors, etc.
10 this is an example of a thread blocking on itself - practicing concurrency 101, monitors, etc.
11 this is an example of a thread blocking on itself - practicing concurrency 101, monitors, etc.
9 this is an example of a thread blocking on itself - practicing concurrency 101, monitors, etc.
8 this is an example of a thread blocking on itself - practicing concurrency 101, monitors, etc.
18 this is an example of a thread blocking on itself - practicing concurrency 101, monitors, etc.
19 this is an example of a thread blocking on itself - practicing concurrency 101, monitors, etc.
17 this is an example of a thread blocking on itself - practicing concurrency 101, monitors, etc.
16 this is an example of a thread blocking on itself - practicing concurrency 101, monitors, etc.
15 this is an example of a thread blocking on itself - practicing concurrency 101, monitors, etc.
```

Since `SimpleBlock()` is not synchronized, I was expecting the prints to be chopped randomly. At least, that's what happened with another synchronization test I ran a while back, except that time I was using Semaphores (or lack thereof).

**So why does each Thread print the full string in such a nice orderly fashion?**

And this leads me to my next inquiry.

Let's say that `simpleBlock` is fully synchronized, and the output is the same as above. So,

```
    synchronized void simpleBlock() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println(i + " this is an example of a thread blocking on itself - practicing concurrency 101, monitors, etc.");
        wait();
    }
```

As you may already know, this is equivalent to

```
    void simpleBlock() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized(this) {
            System.out.println(i + " this is an example of a thread blocking on itself - practicing concurrency 101, monitors, etc.");
            this.wait();
        }
    }
```

Am I correct in assuming that since 20 threads are created in the Main class above, no two threads synchronize on a shared object since each thread is its own unique object, and because of this, synchronization schemes will effectively fail?

In other words, **is it a bad idea to create many threads, each synchronizing on itself?**

Comment: Yes, it's a bad idea to create many threads, each synchronizing on itself. In fact, it's a bad idea to synchronize on  a `Thread` object at all, as it can interfere with `wait` and `notify`. And in general it's a bad idea to extend `Thread`. It's better to extend `Runnable` (which, if you used the same runnable in all threads in this case, would have made all the threads synchronize on the same object).

Comment: Could you elaborate on why it's a bad idea to extend Thread?

Comment: See [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread).

Comment: What an excellent page. Classic SO!! Thank you for sharing.

Comment: By the way, how can I deal with each Runnable object needing to maintain its own independent set of instance variables? It seems to me like the only way to do that is to create a unique Runnable object for each Thread, and suddenly this doesn't seem much better than just extending the Thread class. What are your thoughts?

Comment: Synchronize on some other, single object, which you'll pass in the constructor of all runnables so that it's shared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PrintStream.println` is `synchronized` so your output is relatively orderly even if you have lots of threads.

From the source

```
/**
 * Prints a String and then terminate the line.  This method behaves as
 * though it invokes <code>{@link #print(String)}</code> and then
 * <code>{@link #println()}</code>.
 *
 * @param x  The <code>String</code> to be printed.
 */
public void println(String x) {
    synchronized (this) {
        print(x);
        newLine();
    }
}
```